# Большие числа

Tags: .net, c#

Какие есть средства в .NET для работы с большими числами? Структура BigInteger не подходит из-за невозможности работать с дробью, тип decimal не подходит из-за ограниченности диапазона значений.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic, смотреть, где написано c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что Вы понимаете под словом "большие"?
BigInteger позволяет работать с **целыми** числами произвольного размера.  Если вас интересуют дроби, то, например [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RationalNumbers.aspx) можно найти исходники библиотеки, поддерживающей рациональные числа. Она реализована на основе BigInteger.

По своему опыту могу сказать, что BigInteger - это очень не быстро, по сравнению с int или long.

Answer (score 0):

Можете создать свой тип под средством класса String, но дело в том что, что Вы потом сможете сделать с этим типом? Ведь его не перевести в часто используемый int или другие типы. Хотя его можно использовать как текст, при выполнении унарных и бинарных операций изменять значение из текста.